# Find the CDF with a given random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $X$ is a random variable with a uniform distribution $U(0,1)$. Let $Y$ be a random variable defined with:

$Y=\begin{cases}X & ,0<X\leq\frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{1}{2} & ,\frac{1}{2}<X\leq\frac{2}{3} \\ \frac{3}{2}X-\frac{1}{2} & ,\frac{2}{3}<X<1  \end{cases}$

Find the CDF for $Y$.

What bothers me is the 2nd case in which $Y=\frac{1}{2}$.
Should then $Fy$ be defined as $Fy=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}f(x)dx +\frac{1}{2} \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{x}f(x)dx$

where $f(x)=1$ for this distribution?

Comment: $Y$ will have a point mass at $Y=\frac12$, so the CDF $F_Y$ will have a jump there; it is otherwise continuous.

Comment: So in the 2nd interval $Fy$ won't have a value? @MPW

Comment: @YujieZha What you've written is the CDF in the 2nd or 3th interval?

Comment: @YujieZha Okay, I know how to deal with the 1st an 3th interval but can you explain me what happened with $Fy$ when $x\in (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3})$ ?

Comment: @YujieZha : You are very wrong about this. See my answer. Note that $\Pr(Y\leq\tfrac12 + \epsilon)$ is more than $\Pr(Y\leq\tfrac12 - \epsilon)$ by *at least* $\Pr(\tfrac12<X\leq\tfrac23)=\tfrac16$ no matter how small $\epsilon$ is, so there is definitely a jump there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to compute directly that
$$F_Y(y) = \Pr(Y\leq y)=\begin{cases}
0, & y\leq 0\\
y, & 0 < y <\tfrac12 \\
\tfrac13 + \tfrac23y, & \tfrac12 \leq y \leq 1\\
1, & y > 1
\end{cases}$$

Note that $F_Y(\tfrac12-) = \tfrac12$ but $F_Y(\tfrac12)=\tfrac23$. This is because $Y$ has a point mass at $Y=\tfrac12$ since $\Pr(Y=\tfrac12)=\tfrac16$. This means the graph of $F_Y(y)$ has a jump at $y=\tfrac12$ of size $\tfrac16$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @DraganZrilić : You're welcome. Note that you really have $$F_Y(y) = \int_{g^{-1}((-\infty,y))} f_X(x)\; dx$$where $Y=g(X)$